# How to load key value pairs into hive table?

Tags: hadoop, hive

Below is my data set:

```
Jun name="balaji" id=101

Mar name="kumar" id=102
```

Created table:

```
create table sample(month string,name string, id int)
row format delimited fields terminated by 'space' map keys terminated by '=';
```

Result:

```
select * from sample;      
JUN name="balaji" NULL
Mar name="kumar" NULL
```

Expected result:

```
JUN balaji 101

Mar kumar 102
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create tables like this:

```
create table sample(mnth string,names map<string,string>,ids map<string,int>)
row format delimited fields terminated by ' ' map keys terminated by '=';
```

Select query should be:

```
  select mnth,names["name"],ids["id"]  from sample;

    result: 
      Jun   "balaji"    101
      Mar   "kumar" 102
```

If you fire `select *` from sample:

```
   Jun  {"name":"\"balaji\""}   {"id":101}
   Mar  {"name":"\"kumar\""}    {"id":102}
```

For accessing each value in map you need to pass like  `names["name"]`.

Comment: is it possible to create table for the data set mentioned below,

name="balaji" id=100
name="kumar" fname="some" id=102

data will be changed dynamically it doesnt have proper schema.

how to load this kind of data into hive table..

Comment: Hive doesn't build a dynamic schema from the data it encounters.can you post it in other question with data set.may be people will help you.