# How to get a query result into a key value form in HiveQL

Tags: bigdata, etl, hiveql

I have tried different things, but none succeeded. I have the following issue, and would be very gratefull if someone could help me.

I get the data from a view as several billions of records, for different measures

A)

```
| s_c_m1 | s_c_m2 | s_c_m3 | s_c_m4 | s_p_m1 | s_p_m2 | s_p_m3 | s_p_m4 |
|--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------|
|   0    |   1    |   2    |   3    |   4    |   5    |   6    |   7    |
|   1    |   2    |   3    |   4    |   5    |   6    |   7    |   8    |
|   2    |   3    |   4    |   5    |   6    |   7    |   8    |   9    |
|--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------|
```

Then I need to aggregate it by each measure. And so long so fine. I got this figured out.

B)

```
| s_c_m1 | s_c_m2 | s_c_m3 | s_c_m4 | s_p_m1 | s_p_m2 | s_p_m3 | s_p_m4 |
|--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------|
|   3    |   6    |   9    |   12   |   15   |   18   |   21   |   24   |
|--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------|
```

Then I need to get the data in the following form. I need to turn it into a key-value form.

C)

```
| measure |  c |  p | 
|---------+----+----|
|    m1   |  3 | 15 | 
|    m2   |  6 | 18 | 
|    m3   |  9 | 21 | 
|    m4   | 12 | 24 | 
|---------+----+----|
```

The first 4 columns from B) would form in C) the first column, and the second 4 columns would form another column.

Is there an elegant way, that could be easily maintainable? The perfect solution would be if another measure would be introduced in A) and B), there no modification would be required and it would automatically pick up the difference.

I know how to get this done in SqlServer and Postgres, but here I am missing the expirience.

Comment: Have a look at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-Built-inTable-GeneratingFunctions(UDTF)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use map for this

Comment: I suggest adding more information to this suggestion, which atm is not really an answer. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I think below link should help you, have a look:
[How to load key value pairs into hive table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29159173/how-to-load-key-value-pairs-into-hive-table)